# How can I get the color of the sprite my mouse is over?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(I'm bad at english)
Ok so i'm making a 2d game in Unity where you can place flowers I have a sprite as a background and I only want you to be able to place flowers where the sprite is green like grass. anyone know how to get the color of where the mouse is on the sprite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Capture the color from screen in mouse position using Unity and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905408/how-to-capture-the-color-from-screen-in-mouse-position-using-unity-and-c)

Comment: Check it out...

Comment: Does your background color change where they can plant flowers?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following:

1) In your cursor class, define an `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)` event (this is built in with Unity)

2) Within the trigger, cast the `Collider2D` to a gameobject and get its `SpriteRenderer` component. You can do this with `gameObject.GetComponent<T>` where `T` in your case will be of type `SpriteRenderer`.
(Please note that this is not friendly with performance, you should have components like this defined as a public property, but that's besides the point).

3) If the cast was successful check if the `SpriteRenderer.color == Color.green`